# Latest web browser compatible with Windows 95 / 98

Tags: windows-98, windows-95, internet

Do you know which is the latest web browser compatible with Windows 95 / 98?
At the moment I have an Opera 10 working fine; it is very lightweight but very outdated.

I assume that software that works in Windows 95 will work in Windows 98.

Comment: Does the kind of browser matter? I'm sure the latest version of elinks can be ported to it...

Comment: I'm reasonably sure I am running Firefox 2.0.0.20 on my W98 box (I'm 3000 miles away at the moment).  It works fine for many retro-oriented sites.  I regularly use it to hit AmiNet and then RS-232 the downloads to my Amiga.

Comment: In case it wasn't obvious, surfing the web with an old browser and an old OS exposes you to roughly a gazillion 3000day exploits. A Bad Idea. Perhaps in a VM which you reset after each session. But to browse the web you do need to be networked which will require careful setup to protect other machines on your LAN. And you may become a spam or DDoS bot within a minute or two, bothering other people.

Comment: @Peter, but on the other hand, how many exploits are there in the wild that can survive in a W98 environment? In practice, using _uncommon_ environment (esp. OS and browser) by itself greatly reduces the risk.

Comment: Opera up to v12 is what I use. Any version before adapting the new GUI should work.

Comment: You may just want to Remote Desktop to a modern Windows and then copy downloaded files and such to your local machine.

Comment: https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/10012/modern-browser-that-will-work-in-windows-98se is related, though admittedly 5 years old. The answers are for most part are the same.

Comment: "I assume that software that works in Windows 98 will work in Windows 95" - this is a bad assumption to make. The Win32 API and the OS kernel was improved considerably between 95 (and its OSR releases, like USB support) and 98 and 98SE. Some software only runs on 98SE (such as some Visual Studio tools). Many games are also 98-exclusive. I think Windows ME was the only release of 9x that didn't introduce any major new features that software depended on.

Comment: @Dai You reversed the version numbers when you quoted it. The original statement looks like it was meant to be read as "I assume that Win98 won't break anything that worked on Win95."

Comment: @ssokolow I didn't reverse it, the OP did. I posted my reply before the OP edited the question to reverse it. Look at the question-post's edit history: it was reversed on 2019-05-01, but I posted my reply on 2019-04-18.

Comment: @Dai Ahh. Sorry. I got lazy there.

Comment: Bonus points for providing links that work from IE3 so it can be downloaded directly from the actual Win95 installation ;)

Comment: Haven't tested it, but Links (http://links.twibright.com/) works in DOS (with support for TLS 1.2!!). Since Win95 and Win98 run on MS-DOS 7 there may be a way to make it work

Comment: Retrozilla is a good option: https://rn10950.github.io/RetroZillaWeb/

Answer (score 28):

That latest web browser I am able to find is [K-Meleon 74 Windows 9x Edition](https://retrosystemsrevival.blogspot.com/2018/05/k-meleon-74-windows-9x-edition.html). It was created in 2014, when the Pale Moon engine (Goanna) was backported for Windows 2000. It requires [KernelEx](http://kernelex.sourceforge.net/) (and [the latest updates](https://retrosystemsrevival.blogspot.com/2018/05/kernelex-45201617-updates.html)) and a rather beefy old machine to run.

You could also experiment with other later browser versions on top of KernelEx, as it adds NT support to Windows 98. If not, then you're stuck with the official latest versions, of which Opera 10 is probably the best.

Comment: I see that K-Meleon by roytam1 has newer beta releasessuch as KM76.1.1-Goanna-20190309 (based in Goanna3). As I cannot find the requirements, I understand that they probably require a winXP.

Comment: @DanielPerez KernelEx does try to simulation Windows XP, if you tell it too. So it probably wouldn't hurt to try it. But you are correct that usually the limit is Windows 2000, as XP introduced a bunch of new stuff.

Comment: Opera 11.64 is the last 'tested' version for kernelex it seems, though there seems to be workarounds for some versions of 12 - http://kernelex.sourceforge.net/wiki/Opera

Answer (score 26):

I have not tried any of these, not having a Windows 98 system, but a bit of research reveals:

- Internet Explorer 6 SP1 was the last IE, in 2001.
- Firefox 2 was the last Firefox in 2006.
- Netscape 8 (2005) or Netscape 9 (2007) are available [here](http://sillydog.org/narchive/).
- Opera 10 (2009) seems to be the last available, [here](http://www.oldapps.com/opera.php?system=Windows_98).
- Safari and Chrome never supported Windows 98.

Browsers carried on supporting Windows XP for much longer, because it was a better platform for software development and testing.

This answer was written before the question was edited to add Windows 95. It's not safe to assume that anything which runs on '98 will run on '95; the reverse is more likely to be true.

Comment: Strictly speaking all of these are nearly unusable.  Javascript is VERY difference now (I worked as a web dev dealing with IE6 compatibility issues).  Almost no website will work using a browser that is more than 10 years old.

Comment: @Nelson As someone who occasionally browses with javascript completely disabled, I can say this simply isn't true. Many major websites work fine, although others don't. Any my goodness, the web is much faster with no javascript.

Comment: As someone who still regularly uses Opera 12, I can say that the biggest problem is not so much javascript, but rather the websites which [foolishly] only support https with TLS 1.3.

Comment: @Zeus why is it foolish to not support older, less secure TLS and SSL versions?

Comment: @Moo, because an overwhelming majority of websites don't really require _any_ security to bother with at all. But more specifically, the _practical_ security improvements of TLS 1.3 do not justify breaking backward compatibility and thereby _forcing_ an upgrade (a despicable current trend). For all but some specific cases (like banking), TLS 1.2 (and often even plain http) is _just fine_. It should be _my_ choice to select between security and usability (or other costs).

Comment: @Zeus I disagree - every website should always have the best security available, no exceptions.  Why should it be solely your choice to weaken security when there are two parties involved - you and the website.  Every website has something to lose.

Comment: Well, in most cases they really have nothing to lose except me as a customer. This 'weakening' is like having a 50 mm armoured door instead of 60 mm for your house. But I'm fine with my beautiful oak door. So let's agree to disagree and not continue such discussion here.

Comment: @Zeus At a minimum, the user needs to be confident that the web site they are at is the one they think they are at, which means there needs to be a certificate on the web site that the user trusts and it needs to match the URL the user typed in. And the mechanism to verify the certificate needs to be as secure as possible. You need TLS and it needs to be a fairly modern version.

Comment: @Zeus First of all, 99% of users have no way to assess what level of security they want or need. From a websites perspective there's also frankly no sane reason why they'd lower their security standards just because some stubborn users refuse to upgrade their outdated systems.

Comment: @Cubic, I'm not going to discuss the old tired argument 'people are too stupid to make right decisions', but more on-topic (even generally for RC.SE :) - why refuse to upgrade? - for example, because _no_ browser ever closely approached usability of Opera 12. To the point that I'm prepared to sacrifice some of _my_ security for that usability.

Comment: @Zeus I'm not asking you why you refuse to upgrade. I genuinely don't care. I'm explaining to you why website operators don't care either.

Comment: @JeremyP+ certificate authentication/validation is independent of TLS/SSL version, but has its own issues: certs valid today use SHA-2 since both MD5 and SHA-1 have been broken for collision, but XP didn't support SHA-2 until SP3 in 2008, so I expect 2k and 9x didn't at all. Plus most of the CAs used today didn't exist in the 90s and so won't be in the truststore unless manually fixed. It might work to 'outboard' TLS: route old browser through a proxy like nginx or haproxy that does modern TLS upstream. This could also do HTTP/1.1 if necessary.

Comment: @Zeus Run Opera 12 in a VM then. Since you seem to know better than the combined wisdom of OS and internet security experts.

Answer (score 20):

It very much depends on what you're trying to do - [Lynx](https://lynx.invisible-island.net/release/)'s latest release is from 2018, runs on Win95, and is *very* lightweight, but, you know, lacks graphics.
I also use [Dillo](https://www.dillo.org/Compatibility.html) on old machines when I just need Wikipedia. (Yeah, it does not have nice prebuilt Win binaries as far as I can tell.)
// would've like to comment, but I lack the reputation!

Comment: Basic browsing functions are enough, in fact such small amount of RAM would not be able to render sophisticated and heavy weight pages. But having a browser under support is always better.

Comment: Some quick research in the graphical realm also yielded [Netsurf](http://www.netsurf-browser.org) and [Links](http://links.twibright.com) -- haven't tried either, yet. Neither mentions which Windows *versions* are supported & I don't have a VM at hand, but both support other *really old* OSs, so chances are good. And both seem to be actively developed.

Answer (score 9):

You could run [Web Rendering Proxy](https://github.com/tenox7/wrp) ([screenshots](https://virtuallyfun.com/wordpress/2014/03/11/web-rendering-proxy-update/)) on a server, the browser would just be displaying pre-rendered images with imagemaps.

Comment: If you are going this way, you can run VNC client and have a complete Linux desktop at your disposal. Though most likely you'll have problems with entering non-ASCII characters.

Answer (score 7):

IE6 was the last Internet Explorer on Windows98 SE and IE5.5 with high encryption pack for Windows95. These were important for Citrix, and quite a bit of software leveraged IE6 dll's, notably Ultra-Edit.

Seamonkey 1.1.19 - March 2010, a bit Retro. Not as recent as a better answer.

Answer (score 1):

This won't be the last one, but for Mozilla Firefox, the last version supporting Windows 98 (without hacks) was [Firefox 2.0.0.20](https://website-archive.mozilla.org/www.mozilla.org/firefox_releasenotes/en-us/firefox/2.0.0.20/releasenotes/#uninstall), released on December 18, 2008, support for98/Me [was removed](https://www-archive.mozilla.org/support/firefox/faq#win98icon) on [Firefox 3](https://website-archive.mozilla.org/www.mozilla.org/firefox_releasenotes/en-us/firefox/3.0/releasenotes/#uninstall).

Answer (score 1):

There are assemblies US versions TLS 1.0-1.2 SSL browser based on declared under windows 98 here: http://www.fdd5-25.net/networks.htm#win9x
Example of work here: http://gallery.fdd5-25.net/details.php?image_id=5370

Comment: Thanks for the link to a useful repository of binaries for web browsing under Windows 3.1 onward. However, this doesn't contain any dates for the software, so wouldn't be very useful for answering the question without further research. RCSE discourages link-only answers, so it would be better to include a bit more detail about which of these applications you are recommending.